# Can I use a docker container to keep static files so other docker containers can acces to it?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, directory-structure

I'm building two microservices and dockerizing them. I have a folder that contains a script (`PackageA`) which I need in both services (`ServiceA & B`). My folder structure is as following:

```
Root
|
|--Docker
   |--ProjectA
      |-docker-compose.yml (builds ServiceA & ServiceB)
|--Services
   |--PackageA
      |-src
      |-index.js
      |-package.json

   |--ServiceA
      |-src
      |-index.js
      |-Dockerfile
      |-package.json

   |--ServiceB
      |-src
      |-index.js
      |-Dockerfile
      |-package.json
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  mynetwork:

services:
  servicea:
    build: ./../../Services/ServiceA
    container_name: servicea
    ports:
      - ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  serviceb:
    build: ./../../Services/ServiceB
    ports: serviceb
      - ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

In both services th `Dockrfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . ./
EXPOSE ...
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

So my question is: Could I dockerize also `PackageA` and create a volume with its content, and then using that volume in `ServiceA & B`? How could I share volumes between containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a good thing to go for this style of architecture. They are not microservices if they are coupled in this fashion. You would do better to publish your shared library or even do a bit of copying and pasting to duplicate the code.

However, technically speaking, it's possible. You could do something along these lines:

The Dockerfile, for the shared service, creates some dummy content in the directory `/shared`.

```
FROM busybox

WORKDIR /shared
RUN echo "shared content" > /shared/data.txt
```

Then 2 services are started. Both mounting a shared volume. The shared service mounts the volume first because app-a has a `depends_on` with `condition`.

```yaml
name: example

services:
  shared:
    build: ./
    volumes: [ shared:/shared ]
  app-a:
    image: busybox
    command: cat /shared/data.txt
    volumes: [ shared:/shared ]
    depends_on:
      shared:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  shared:
```

```
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Network example_default     Created                                                                                                                                                                     0.6s
 ⠿ Volume "example_shared"     Created                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container example-shared-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 ⠿ Container example-app-a-1   Created                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
Attaching to example-app-a-1, example-shared-1
example-shared-1 exited with code 0
example-app-a-1   | shared content
example-app-a-1 exited with code 0
```

When an empty named volume is mounted, the content of the container's file system is first copied into the volume and then its mounted.

That way, app-a, *sees* the shared content.

Sometimes you may also want to let the shared service populate the volume on startup, manually. Because what I am doing here is very specific to docker. It would not work in Kubernetes, for example. There you had to copy the shared content into the volume when the shared service starts.

```yaml
shared:
  image: busybox
  command: sh -c 'echo "shared content" > /shared/data.txt'
  volumes: [ shared:/shared ]
```

Comment: Thanks for that elaborated answer. It has helped me to understand more about docker and docker compose. Publishing the package sounds a goo idea to me. If I publish it via npm, later I can use it like a normal npm package installing it via `npm i PackageA` right?,

Comment: @ask4you, yes, you can publish it to a package artifactory like NPM. Potentially private so that only you can use it. However,  some people do not advise opting for this when creating microservices, because this also creates coupling. That's why,  said, you could even copy the code. See https://phauer.com/2016/dont-share-libraries-among-microservices/, for example. You will find more material online.

Comment: Yea, at the end is the same point. But I didn't want to have them repeated in both services. Thank you for your answers

Comment: @ask4you, if they share business logic like this, maybe they are not separate services.

Comment: I mean the package is just an implementation I made to manage Apache Kafka connection with nodejs. Thats why I need to use It as a shared library, so they can comunicate with each other.

Comment: @ask4you, so its more like a general purpose library. In that case it could make sense to publish this to some artifactory. Just like a sql client or similar packages.